# How can I get the size of a vector that is inside another vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm having trouble getting the size of a vector by dot-walking from a parent vector into the one in question. I have verified that calling the function `myfunc 1 2 3 4 5` creates five Person objects and puts them in the `left` vector. But when I try to get that same size to return by dot-walking from `bridge` to `left`, I get 0 as the size.

What am I doing wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Person* p_ptr;
    int id_source = 0;
    vector<Person> left;
    vector<Person> right;
    bridge.push_back(left);
    bridge.push_back(right);
    cout << "bridge.size() = " << bridge.size() << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
      id_source++;
      cout << "Creating Person with crossing speed of " << argv[i] << " and id of " << id_source << endl;
      p_ptr = new Person(atoi(argv[i]), id_source);
      left.push_back(*p_ptr);
    }
    /*SIZE TESTING*/
    cout << "Left side of bridge has " << left.size() << " people on it " << endl;
    cout << "bridge.at(0).size() = " << bridge.at(0).size() << endl;
    cout << "bridge.at(1).size() = " << bridge.at(1).size() << endl;
    int slowest_id = get_slowest(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < left.size(); i++) {
      if (slowest_id == left.at(i).get_id()) {
        p_ptr = &left.at(i);
      }
    }
    cout << "The slowest person has id of " << slowest_id << " and speed of " << p_ptr->get_crossing_time() << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Seeing `new` in your code makes me sad. :-(  || ..Worse of all, I didn't see a corresponding `delete`. Prefer [smart pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30143936/1621391). You'll not regret using them

Comment: Why? I can clean up at the end of the program.

EDIT: I'm not done with the program, that's why there isn't a `delete`.

Comment: your `bridge` contains a copy of `left` so any changes to `left` will not be reflected on `bridge`'s version of left

Comment: You should look up RAII. If an exception is thrown in a function, you might wind up with a memory leak or invalid pointers.

Comment: @MyLoneTrojan Concur on RAII, but no "might" about it regarding memory leaks. Even without exceptions, this already has memory leaks. That entire `new` logic is unnecessary, and guaranteed to leak memory for each and every insert into `left`

Comment: Why use new when you are going to dereference it in your push_back call?

Comment: the memory allocated by `new Person(atoi(argv[i]), id_source);` is leaked with no way of retrieving it, since you reassign `p_ptr` the next loop iteration. More to the point this is completely unnecessary, you can and should put a Person in the vector without using `new`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`left` and `bridge[0]` are two different lists.  When you call `bridge.push_back(left)` you make a copy of the current `left` list (which is empty).  Elements added later will not be in the `bridge` version.

Comment: So, I should make bridge a `vector <vector<&Person> >` as opposed to `vector< vector<Person> >`? Because then all changes to the internal vectors would be reflected.

Comment: Nope. Just remembered you can't have a vector of references (plus that syntax was wrong anyway). But I guess I could do a `vector< vector<Person>* >`.